# C# like verbatim string in Rust?

Tags: rust, verbatim-string

I am looking for a verbatim strings in Rust (like in C# with `@"This is a string and here ""I am between quotes without making a fuss"""`).

Is there something similar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/std/str.html#literals-and-escapes) is surprisingly difficult to find.

In rust, raw string literals are surrounded by `r""`, and add `#` if you need to use quotes.
For your example, 

`r#"This is a string and here "I am between quotes without making a fuss""#` 

should work. (Double-quoting will produce doubled quotes in the string.)

If you need something with the `#` symbol, you can do something like 

`r###"This string can have ## in as many places as I like ##, but never three in a row ##"###`

However, in rust raw strings, escapes are disallowed. You cannot use `\n`, for example. You can, however include any UTF-8 character you want.

Comment: Aw too bad I thought adding some new lines at some point.
But fair enough will play with the Rust rules.
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: To be clear: It will look really odd, but you can include the newline character in the raw literal.. If you read the link I provided, some more explanation is provided.

Answer (score 3):

I guess [raw string literals](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.7.0/reference.html#raw-string-literals) you are looking for ?

```
 let raw_string_literal = r#" line1 \n still line 1"#;
 println!("{}", raw_string_literal);
```